# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;

Tags: java, arrays, class, exception, toarray

when I'm executing the below code I'm getting Class cast exception. I believe in an object is trying to cast with class can anyone help me

```
 public abstract AGridFilterMenu refreshFilters();


 public AGridFilterMenu supportFilter(String style, Class<? extends AFilterItem> clazz, By... childLocators) {
      ArrayList<Class<By>> signature = new ArrayList<>();
      for(int i = 0; i< childLocators.length; i++) {
          signature.add(By.class);
      }

      try {
        Constructor<? extends AFilterItem> construct = clazz.getConstructor((Class<?>[]) signature.toArray());
        constructors.put(style, construct);
        filteritemChildLocators.put(style, childLocators);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        throw new TestCodeException("Unsupported FilterItem signature", e);
    }
      return this;
  }

  public AFilterItem getFilter(String filterName) {
    logger.trace(String.format("Retrieving filter %s", filterName));
    AFilterItem item = filters.get(filterName);`enter code here`
    item.bind();
    return item;
  }
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post and add the COMPLETE stack trace; indicate which statement in your code throws the exception.

Comment: Please provide exact error an also mention on which line you are getting exception..

Comment: Please share your debugging details, people here can help you more clearly if you  stage your question more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is method `Object[] List.toArray()` returns an array of `Object` and it cannot be cast to array of `Class<?>`.

Luckily, there's a more suitable method `T[] List.toArray(T[])`, but you need to prepare an array instance of particular size and type to store the result.

Keep in mind that in case of `ArrayList` both argument and returning value are the same instance of array, which is mutating inside the `toArray` method.

```
Class<?>[] signatureArray = new Class<?>[signature.size()];
signature.toArray(signatureArray);
Constructor<? extends AFilterItem> construct = clazz.getConstructor(signatureArray);
```

Comment: You do not have to prepare a size matching array. It's just better performance, because a size matching array is used directly. Otherwise, a size matching array is created. I use either a constant zero sized array or indeed a new size matching array.

Comment: @jokster, you're right - the precise contract of the method is in javadoc.